# Extract from last slash till the end in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with an `url` column with urls like so:

```
https://shop.domain.com/product/12345/this-is-great-product
```

I need to extract the last part from the last slash to the end:

```
this-is-great-product
```

I was planning in using something REGEXP_SUBSTR but its an extension that I don want to install.
How can i do this in SQLite version 3.39.4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JSON: convert your delimited string (url) into a valid JSON array, then take the last element:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS urls(url);
DELETE FROM urls;
INSERT INTO urls(url) VALUES ('https://shop.domain.com/product/12345/this-is-great-product');

SELECT json_extract('["' || replace(url, '/', '", "') || '"]', '$[#-1]') AS suffix FROM urls;
```

See the [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gpe5989LpSrY7XCEQJSBhB/0).